# forcing elements to the same level with equal borders (inline-block alone/float:left; clear:right doesn't work)

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, django-templates

I have a fiddle below with some elements using inline block that fall to the same line, but not always to equal levels. Every google says to simple use inline-block. I also followed a "float:left; clear: right;" example, to no avail.

The most surprising attempt that still failed was clearing elements to the right for every third article in django template:

```
            {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}
                <div style="clear:right;" class="article-link">
            {% else %}
                <div  class="article-link">
            {% endif %}
```

This caused:

[image]
How can I make these articles all start at the exact same level, regardless of box size? So always 3 on a line, at the same height, then a new line, all at the same height? Thank you

https://jsfiddle.net/codyc54321/ctp4n3og/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a vertical-align, removed float, made width 30%.  It's working on my FireFox. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ctp4n3og/3/)

```
article {
    padding:10px;
    min-height: 190px;
    border: 1px groove #A17157;
}

.article-link{
    vertical-align: text-top;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 13px 14px 0;
    padding:0;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:30%;
}
```